# Image not displaying in Windows Phone 8 App

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a C#/XAML Windows Phone 8 App.  In it, I'm trying to display an image on top of the screen; however, when I do so, it doesn't appear.

Here's my image:

```
<Image Grid.Row ="1" Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.Column ="1"
       Width ="150" Height ="100"
       Visibility ="Collapsed" x : Name="MyImage">
     <Image.RenderTransform>
          <ScaleTransform CenterX ="75" CenterY="50">
          </ScaleTransform>
     </Image.RenderTransform>
</Image>
```

This is part of an animation (here's the storyboard):

```
<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName ="MyImage"
                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"
                 From ="0" To ="1" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName ="MyImage"
                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"
                 From ="0" To ="1" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
```

And I trigger the animation like this:

```
BitmapImage newImage = new BitmapImage ();
newImage.UriSource = new Uri( "ms-appx:///Assets/MyImage.png" ); // Can change
MyImage.Source = newImage;
MyImage.Visibility = Visibility .Visible;

Storyboard sbExpand = (Storyboard )this.Resources[storyboardName];
sbExpand.Completed += sbExpand_Completed;
sbExpand.Begin();
```

I know this works, because if I replace the image with a button, it does what I expect.  Why doesn't the image display?  Is an image even the right control to use in this circumstance?

Comment: Are your sure this image exists? What's the VS output? Can you set this image statically (from XAML) just to check if it's displayed in normal circumstances?

Comment: When you say it does what you expect... what exactly is it?

Comment: @PiotrJustyna Yes, it displays fine on a blank form, the image is set to always copy and marked as content.  My guess is that it's appearing in the background or something.

Comment: What I expect is for the control to appear and grow larger (as per the animation)

Comment: Does it appear even if you specify the "Source" directly in XAML for your "MyImage" (not on a blank form)? What can you see in the "newImage" object when you set a breakpoint on this line: MyImage.Visibility = Visibility .Visible;?

Comment: on your storyboard completed..event set your Myimage visibility to visible..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use on Windows Phone 8 for Image Source the URI scheme ms-appx, it works only in Windows 8 projects.
You can check my blog article here, how to properly link images in resources/isolated storage using Uri:

[Image path databinding in WP8 and Windows 8 apps](http://suchan.cz/2013/05/image-path-databinding-in-wp8-and-windows-8-apps/)

Comment: May thanks.  It is not at all clear that this is the case fro MS documentation.  For those that come after, the WP8 way that seemed to work for me was: new uri("//Assets/MyImage.png")